# Pointer to Pointer array & Stack Smashing error

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I need to allocate an array with a malloc and I have to read some numbers from input. This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void read(int **array, int *array_size)
{
    int *tmp;
    int i;
    scanf("%d", array_size);
    *array=malloc(*array_size*sizeof(int));
    tmp=malloc(*array_size*sizeof(int));
    for(i=0;i<*array_size;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &tmp[i]);
        array[i]=&tmp[i];
    }
}

//DO NOT EDIT main()
int main()
{
    int *array;
    int array_size,i;

    read(&array,&array_size);

    printf("Print array:\n");
    for(i=0;i<array_size;i++)
        printf("%d\n", array[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

It kinda works, but after displaying values it shows a ***stack smashing detected*** (I compiled it with GCC).

I thought the problem is that `*array=malloc(*array_size*sizeof(int))`, but I can't figure out how to fix it. Is there another way to allocate this array without editing main()? Thank you.

Comment: Array_size isn't even initialized...

Comment: BTW the `#include`s are absolute necessary for MCVE. In absence of `<stdlib.h>` `malloc` will misbehave badly on 64-bit platforms.

Comment: @TonyTannous considering scanf success.....it's OK.

Comment: @SouravGhosh indeed I didn't notice the `scanf`.
Why passing an argument to a function when it reads it from the user inside the function ?
Extra space on stack for function parameters. I would do it anyway outside.

Comment: tmp should be an int, not a pointer. at least you should free it after using.

Comment: It works or it doesn't work. There's no "kinda". In your case it doesn't work. `array[i]=&tmp[i];` is a red alert. Taking an address of a *temporary*? Nope nope nope nope, cannot possibly be right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you're indexing the *wrong* array. You should be writing `(*array)[i]`, not `array[i]`:

```
void read(int **array, int *array_size)
{
    int *tmp;
    int i;
    scanf("%d", array_size);
    *array=malloc(*array_size*sizeof(int));
    tmp=malloc(*array_size*sizeof(int));
    for(i=0;i<*array_size;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &tmp[i]);
        (*array)[i]=tmp[i];
    }
}
```

Of course all this is very complicated - you don't need to actually have that `tmp`, nor do you need to `malloc` it. Instead you could very well do something like

```
void read(int **array, int *array_size) {
    int i, *pos;
    scanf("%d", array_size);
    *array = pos = malloc(*array_size * sizeof(int));
    for (i = 0; i < *array_size; i ++, pos ++) {
        scanf("%d", pos);
    }
}
```

That is we have the pointer `pos` to point to the current position in the array where we want to `scanf` the next integer. On each loop we increment the position.

Naturally, you'd want to check the return values of these `scanf`s and `malloc`; and perhaps `read` should have a different prototype, such as

```
int *read(int *array_size);
```

so it could return the pointer to the array directly, or NULL on error.